# POST with ajax, php, html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

When the submit button is clicked of a html form i want to post a value to a different php file.

code what i have now is a mix of php and javascript:

```
waar = 1;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    ?><script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: 'zoek.php',
        data: 'waar=' + waar,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(uitkomst) {
            alert("1");
        },
        error: function(request, status, error){
         }
    });
    </script><?php
}
```

In zoek.php i'm getting the code like this:

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['waar'])) {
    ?><script type="text/javascript">
        alert("2");
        alerted = localStorage.getItem('alerted') || '';
        if (alerted == 'yes') {
            localStorage.setItem('alerted','no');
        };
    </script><?php
}
?>
```

It does alert "1" but it does not alert "2".
I'm not sure why this is, because it is succeeded in the ajax call.
But does not seem to recieve the 'POST'.

(sorry for bad english)

Comment: Why you want to post it to different php? You could use curl instead ajax

Comment: what is this? why not just stop the form from submitting, and then make your AJAX call in PHP, then get the response from the server

Comment: @Ghost i also need the form to start sessions. that's not pausible if i stop the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the 1st ajax callback to:

```
function(uitkomst) {
    alert("1");
    $("body").append(uitkomst);
},
```

This adds the response to the DOM, that immediatelly executes the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see an alert for "2" because any JavaScript code on a page that you do an AJAX call to does not run in the page making the call. You'd have to append the response text from the AJAX call into your webpage for the script to actually execute. In your case, that would be the `uitkomst` variable.